# Create SpatialLinesDataFrame from point coordinates

Tags: r, r-sp

I am doing a animal tracking project. My data "finaltrimmed" looks like this

```
  TrackIndex     Time x_position y_position
1             1   0.1034        425        171
2             1   0.1379        425        169
3             1   0.1724        427        166
.........
125          25   1.1030        462        397
126          25   1.1380        462        397
127          25   1.1720        462        397
128          25   1.2070        462        397
129          25   1.2410        461        398
130          25   1.2760        462        399
131          25   1.3100        461        399
132          25   1.3450        461        399
133          25   1.3790        460        399
134          25   1.4140        460        399
.....
268          41   1.8280        302        280
269          41   1.8620        303        279
270          41   1.8970        302        280
271          41   1.9310        302        280
272          41   1.9660        302        281
273          41   2.0000        302        281
274          41   2.0340        302        281
275          41   2.0690        302        282
276          41   2.1030        302        282
277          41   2.1380        302        282
278          41   2.1720        302        283
........
```

I wish to create a line for each unique TrackIndex, which basically tracks how each individual insect move over time. And from there I want create a SpatialLinesDataFrame based on TrackIndex. Eventually, I want to use “buffer”function in “adehabitatMA” package to create a buffer area around each line.

I was able to create a SpatialPointsDataFrame using the following command.

```
xy<-cbind(finaltrimmed$x_position,finaltrimmed$y_position)
MatrixofPoints<-matrix(xy,ncol=2)
points<-SpatialPoints(MatrixofPoints) 
dataframe=data.frame(finaltrimmed$TrackIndex)
df.points<-SpatialPointsDataFrame(points,dataframe)
```

However, I was not able to create a SpatialLinesDataFrame in a similar way.

My idea is to split the data frame “final trimmed” first with “split” function.

```
splitfinal<-split(finaltrimmed,finaltrimmed$TrackIndex)
```

which gives me the following data structure
$`1`
    TrackIndex  Time x_position y_position newindex
 1:       1246 347.0        316        214        1
 2:       1246 347.0        316        214        2
 ......
57:       1246 348.9        325        201       57
58:       1246 349.0        330        201       58
    TrackIndex  Time x_position y_position newindex

$`25`
    TrackIndex  Time x_position y_position newindex
 1:       1318 363.6        375        422        1
 2:       1318 363.7        375        422        2
 .....
57:       1318 365.6        399        406       57
58:       1318 365.6        400        406       58
From there, I can cbind the x and y positions in “splitfinal” (this step didn’t work out because “splitfinal” is a list of lists). I am also not sure how to create a Lines-class, which is required to create a SpatialLinesDataFrame.

I am been stuck for many days and could not figure a way.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Didn't use it myself, but this could work : https://rpubs.com/walkerke/points_to_line

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that should work:

Example data:

```
finaltrimmed <- read.table(text="TrackIndex  Time x_position y_position
1    1   0.1034  425  171
2    1   0.1379  425  169
3    1   0.1724  427  166
130 25   1.2760  462  399
131 25   1.3100  461  399
132 25   1.3450  461  399
133 25   1.3790  460  399
134 25   1.4140  460  399
274 41   2.0340  302  281
275 41   2.0690  302  282
276 41   2.1030  302  282
277 41   2.1380  302  282
278 41   2.1720  302  283")
```

Solution:

```
library(raster)
ft <- split(finaltrimmed, finaltrimmed$TrackIndex)

z <- lapply(ft, function(i) spLines(as.matrix(i[, c('x_position', 'y_position')]), attr=data.frame(TrackIndex=i$TrackIndex[1])))
names(z) <- NULL
zz <- do.call(bind, z)
```